# Role of sizeof in malloc

Tags: c, malloc, size, dynamic-memory-allocation, sizeof

My allocation works partially. However I dont understand the use of `sizeof()`. Also `*num`, I thought the correct use would be `(unsigned short*)num`

I get some errors if I dont use it, but why is it supposed to be used.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>

unsigned short *reverse_seq(unsigned short num) {
    if (num == 0) return NULL;
    unsigned short *ret = malloc((unsigned short)num);             //Works partially
    //unsigned short *ret = malloc(sizeof(unsigned short)*num);    //Correct allocation
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
        ret[i] = num - i;
    return ret;
}

int main() {
    unsigned short *ret = reverse_seq(4u);
    for (unsigned short i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
        printf("%u", ret[i]);
 }
```

Comment: how many bytes do you want to allocate? `num` (which is number of elements) or `num * 2` - which is number of bytes?

Comment: btw, `%u` is for unsinged int (4 bytes), not unsigned short (2 bytes)

Comment: `(unsigned short)num` performs cast from `num` type into unsigned short, but num is already unsigned short, so it performs... nothing

Comment: @IłyaBursov why is num de referenced and then cast in the correct lline.

Comment: there is no num dereference anywhere, `*` is multiplication, you multiple number of elements by size in bytes of single element, thus getting total size in bytes

Comment: and `sizeof(unsigned short)` is not cast, it is expression to get number of bytes occupied by unsigned short

Comment: `ret = malloc((unsigned short)num);` better as `ret = malloc(sizeof ret[0] * num);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter to `malloc` is the number of bytes to allocate.  You are trying to return an array of `unsigned short` with `num` elements.  To get the correct size, you need to multiply the size of a single element `sizeof(unsigned short)` by the number of elements `num`.  Your correctly working statement does exactly that; the `*` is not a dereference but a multiplication.

Comment: very clear, thanks alot.